# Why product of spheres contains wedge of spheres as a CW-subcomplex?

Tags: algebraic-topology, cw-complexes

We have $S^k \times S^l$ with cellular structure $e^0_1\times e^0_2,~ e^k\times e^0_2,~ e^0_1\times e^l,~ e^k\times e^l.$ Why do first three cells form $S^k \vee S^l$?

I mean, if we assume $k<=l$, at first we have a point, then we must glue boundary of a $k$-cell to that point obtaining sphere $S^k$, but then we need to glue boundary of an $l$-cell to $S^k$ and I do not see why it must all be glued to the same point.

Thank you.

Comment: Well, the reason why it’s all glued to the point is that that is the definition of the cell structure on the product! The attaching map of a product of cells is the product of the attaching maps of each factor.

Comment: @KevinCarlson How is product of continuous maps defined?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Kevin in the comments means that the *characteristic map* of the product cell is the product of the characteristic maps of the two factors (rather than the attaching map).

Assume that we have attached an $m$-cell to $X$ and and $n$-cell to $Y$ to give us characteristic maps $\Phi:D^m\rightarrow X\cup e^m$ and $\Psi:D^n\rightarrow Y\cup e^n$. The attaching maps are their restrictions to the boundaries $\partial D^m=S^{m-1}$ and $\partial D^n=S^{n-1}$. i.e. $\phi=\Phi|:S^{m-1}\rightarrow X$ and $\psi=\Psi|:S^{n-1}\rightarrow Y$. If you want to think in terms of a pushout square defining the adjunction space, then the attaching and characterstic maps live on opposite sides of the square.

Now the product of the characteristic maps $\Phi,\Psi$ is simply the map 
$$\Phi\times \Psi:D^m\times D^n\rightarrow (X\cup e^n)\times (Y\cup e^n),\qquad (z_1,z_2)\mapsto (f(z_1),g(z_2)).$$

The point is that there is a homeomorphism $D^m\times D^n\cong D^{m+n}$, which we can see by observing that $D^n\cong I^n$. On the boundary this homeomorphism restricts to a homeomorphism
$$\partial(D^m\times D^n)=(\partial D^m\times D^n)\cup(D^m\times \partial D^n)\cong \partial D^{m+n}$$
which we might prefer to write
$$(S^{m-1}\times D^n)\cup(D^m\times S^{n-1})\cong S^{m+n-1}.$$

To get the *attaching map* of the product cell we simply restrict the characteristic map to the boundary. So if $\Phi\times \Psi$ above is the characteristic map, then the attaching map it defines is $(\Phi\times \Psi)|_{\partial D^{m+n}}$. Using the homeomorphism above this map is exactly
$$(\phi\times\Psi)\cup(\Phi\times\psi):(S^{m-1}\times D^n)\cup(D^m\times S^{n-1})\rightarrow (X\times (Y\cup e^n))\cup ((X\cup e^m)\times Y).$$
where of course the domain is homeomorphic to $S^{n+m-1}$

The point is that we should get a homeomorphism between the product space $(X\cup e^n)\times (Y\cup e^n)$ and $((X\times (Y\cup e^n))\cup ((X\cup e^m)\times Y))\cup e^{n+m}.$

If we take $X=Y=\ast$, then $X\cup e^m\cong S^m$ and $Y\cup e^n\cong S^n$, and the above argument says that there is a homeomorphism

$$S^m\times S^n\cong ((\ast\times S^n)\cup (S^m\times \ast))\cup e^{n+m}=(S^m\vee S^n)\cup e^{m+n}.$$